# How can we add multiple folder paths in same AWS Code Pipeline deployment in a EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-codepipeline

Is it possible to deploy to more then one folders in same EC2 with AWS code pipeline?

I'm trying to deploy to more the one folder with single aws code pipeline

below is the appspec.xml file sample that I'm trying

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/www/folder1
file_exists_behavior: OVERWRITE
```

Is it possible to pass multiple parameters in **destination:** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`destination` should be a single string, however you can use multiple source and destination pairs:

```
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/www/folder1
  - source: /
    destination: /var/www/folder2
```

This [documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-files.html) has more information.

Comment: Above one was working fine thanks @paolo , one of the other issue I realized was, when I use 2 pipelines in same EC2 with same deployment group, only recent enabled one working, any suggestions here?

Comment: @Uba please open a different question for that